# Registry value for Exchange Management Tool

Tags: registry, exchange-server

Is there any registry value to identify whether Exchange management tools is installed in the machine or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\v14\AdminTools
```